# Changing Jenkins $HOME

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables

On our Ubuntu Linux server, Jenkins runs under the `tomcat6` user, which has a non-writable `$HOME` of `/usr/share/tomcat6`.

Some of the tools that our builds run will refuse to work if `$HOME` is non-writable (e.g., `npm install` fails with a cryptic `Error: Attempt to unlock foo, which hasn't been locked`).

What's the best way of handling this? I'd like for Jenkins to instead set `$HOME` to be the same as my `$JENKINS_HOME`, but is there an easy way of doing that, besides editing the "Execute shell" step of every job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install jenkins the official way? My jenkins installation is using /var/lib/jenkins as $HOME for the user jenkins. I think it's the easiest way to solve your issue. Just do as suggested on that page :

http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/

If you really want Tomcat6 to serve your jenkins instance, the relatively easy way I see is to move your tomcat6 user homedir to /var/lib/tomcat6 and give it write permission at this place.

Other than that I guess it requires to edit all jobs manually as you stated above.

Comment: I had installed Jenkins as a WAR under Ubuntu's `tomcat6`. I don't remember now why I did that; using the official Jenkins .deb is easier and, as you said, fixes my problem. Thanks.